# Cartopy pcolormesh with re-normalized colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to plot global Aerosol Optical Depths (AOD), and the values are typically around 0.2, but in some regions can reach 1.2 or more. Ideally I want to plot these high values, without losing the detail of the smaller values. A log scale color bar isn't really appropriate either, so I've tried to use two linear ranges as described in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html?highlight=offsetnorm#custom-normalization-two-linear-ranges):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


class MidpointNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        # I'm ignoring masked values and all kinds of edge cases to make a
        # simple example...
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        res = np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))
        return res
```

This breaks when I try to do a pcolormesh plot with Cartopy though. Creating dummy data as per one of the gallery examples:

```
def sample_data(shape=(73, 145)):
    """Returns ``lons``, ``lats`` and ``data`` of some fake data."""
    nlats, nlons = shape
    lats = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, nlats)
    lons = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, nlons)
    lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
    wave = 0.75 * (np.sin(2 * lats) ** 8) * np.cos(4 * lons)
    mean = 0.5 * np.cos(2 * lats) * ((np.sin(2 * lats)) ** 2 + 2)

    lats = np.rad2deg(lats)
    lons = np.rad2deg(lons)
    data = wave + mean

    return lons, lats, data


ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
lons, lats, data = sample_data()
ax.contourf(lons, lats, data,
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
            cmap='spectral', norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0.8))
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
plt.show()
```

Gives me this, which looks OK:
[image: working contourf plot]

However, when using the pcolormesh equivalent does not seem to work, it has a smeared set of values between 0 and 180 degrees longitude (the right half of the plot) instead of the wavy pattern seen in the contour plot:

```
ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data, 
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
            cmap='spectral', norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0.8))
```

[image: broken pcolormesh plot]

How can I make this work for pcolormesh? I typically see this when I've done something wrong with Cartopy projection/transformation so presumably this is something to do with the way Cartopy does wrapping around the dateline or one of the edge cases the simple matplotlib example ignores, but I can't figure it out.

Note that this only occurs when using the custom Normalization instance; without it, also pcolormesh works as expected.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The pcolormesh example (second plot) has a smeared set of values between 0 and 180 degrees longitude instead of the wavy pattern seen in the contour plot. I typically see this when I've done something wrong with Cartopy projection/transformation...

Comment: OK, thanks. I've edited the question to try and make it clearer. 0-180 degress longitude is the right hand half of the plot, it should be symetric with the left half (as the contour plot is).

Comment: Yes, it's only when using the MidpointNormalize to norm the color scale. Yes, it should be...!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to have something to do with the masking inside the normalization class. 
So here is a version that is working:

```
class MidpointNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        result, is_scalar = self.process_value(value)
        (vmin,), _ = self.process_value(self.vmin)
        (vmax,), _ = self.process_value(self.vmax)
        resdat = np.asarray(result.data)
        result = np.ma.array(resdat, mask=result.mask, copy=False)
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        res = np.interp(result, x, y)
        result = np.ma.array(res, mask=result.mask, copy=False)
        if is_scalar:
            result = result[0]
        return result
```

The complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

class MidpointNormalize(colors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        colors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        result, is_scalar = self.process_value(value)
        (vmin,), _ = self.process_value(self.vmin)
        (vmax,), _ = self.process_value(self.vmax)
        resdat = np.asarray(result.data)
        result = np.ma.array(resdat, mask=result.mask, copy=False)
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        res = np.interp(result, x, y)
        result = np.ma.array(res, mask=result.mask, copy=False)
        if is_scalar:
            result = result[0]
        return result

def sample_data(shape=(73, 145)):
    """Returns ``lons``, ``lats`` and ``data`` of some fake data."""
    nlats, nlons = shape
    lats = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, nlats)
    lons = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, nlons)
    lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
    wave = 0.75 * (np.sin(2 * lats) ** 8) * np.cos(4 * lons)
    mean = 0.5 * np.cos(2 * lats) * ((np.sin(2 * lats)) ** 2 + 2)

    lats = np.rad2deg(lats)
    lons = np.rad2deg(lons)
    data = wave + mean

    return lons, lats, data


ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
lons, lats, data = sample_data()

norm = norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=0.8)
cm = ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data, 
            transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
            cmap='spectral', norm=norm )

ax.coastlines()
plt.colorbar(cm, orientation="horizontal")
ax.set_global()
plt.show()
```

produces

[image]